# Can't send HTTP header parameters from custom service in spring security

Tags: java, spring

Can't send header parameters from my custom service, which I use instead of PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.

I have extended PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices and overridden

```
protected void setCookie(String[] tokens, int maxAge, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
```

method, to send hash value as header paramater, not like cookie. I've tried to send the value using `response.addHeader()`  and `response.setHeader()` methods, but couldn't succeed. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve? are you creating tokens with some external parameter(a hash value)?

Comment: Right, I want my server to send token (hash value) using external parameter through header as a header parameter, not like cookie. I am customizing remember me service. I am altering the server-side, so that when user send his/her credentials, and after successful verification, server sends hash value using through header as a header parameter. Client-side app gets hash through header and next time uses it for authentication/authorization process on the server-side(remember-me).

Comment: Can't you call the login resource from app providing credentials and rather return an XML response with token and corresponding value to client which (token) you can further pass with every call?

Comment: Doesn't work. It sends welcome page content after authentication. Could you please have a look at it(http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/reusing-persistent-token-mechanism-of-spring-security/). Maybe I overlooked something.